# How to display web json data on uitableview on button click

Tags: ios, web-services, uitableview, ios6, uibutton

i am using singleton class for web service calling and display in uitableview ,My function is when i clicked  submit button of new orchardname for new add then view redirect to tableview but data not seen which add recently.  "singOrchard.orcharsList" it's orchard name array which i have to display. "[wOrchrad getorchardslist]" it's my web service call.

```
- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender 
{
    if (Orchadname.text.length == 0) {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DataTree"   message:@"Please Enter OrchardName" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
    }
    else {
        [singOrchard.orcharsList removeAllObjects];
        NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xyz.com"]; // Passing token to URL
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self]; // Support to perform URLrequest
        if (theConnection) { // checking connection successfull or not
            webData1 = [NSMutableData data];
            NSLog(@"Orchard Name is %@", Orchadname.text);
        }

        [wOrchrad getorchardslist];
        NSLog(@"ARRAY COUNT %@",singOrchard.orcharsList);
        [self performSelector:@selector(gotodetails) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
    }
}
```

"[wOrchard getorchardslist]- Singletone+Webserviceutility"

```
- (void)getorchardslist 
{
    orchardsnames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    singltoneclass = [SingletoneClass sharedInstanceMethod];
    theRequest =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xyz.com"]
                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                            timeoutInterval:60.0];
    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
    [theConnection start];
}
```

Comment: can you add code for the method [wOrchrad getorchardslist];

Comment: i added my details, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the return result from theConnection. (At least not in your provided code.) Since you have set your class as the delegate, implement the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods.

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

use it to save your JSON data to an NSArray, which you can then use in your UITableView.

If you send your request asynchrounsly, don't forget to append the data with

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data